GCP - Pub/Sub Add Principal failed - gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com
I'm trying to use Pub/Sub and Gmail API to trigger events based on emails, but I'm having trouble adding principals in Pub/Sub.
When trying to register with the following details:

Service Account: gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com
Role:Pub/Sub Publisher

I encounter the following error and cannot proceed.
The 'Domain Restricted Sharing' organization policy (constraints/iam.allowedPolicyMemberDomains) is enforced. Only principals in allowed domains can be added as principals in the policy. Correct the principal emails and try again.
I'm totally stuck,I need your help, please.
Add Principal Images
I have checked the organization's policy 'constraints/iam.allowedPolicyMemberDomains'.
Check Policy Images

if your going to put images of cloud please set your language to english.

Thank you for your comment. I changed the language setting to English.

I'd not encountered Service Accounts with @system.gserviceaccount.com in their email address prior to your question but that is indeed a valid name. I suspect (!) that your organization is indeed limiting principals and this domain is not included. Service Accounts are generally iam.gserviceaccount.com or {service}.gserviceaccount.com. If you are in an Org and someone else is managing, perhaps bring this to their attention as they may need to include system.gserviceaccount.com.

To change the 'Domain Restricted Sharing' organization policy (constraints/iam.allowedPolicyMemberDomains), the account must have the Organization Policy Administrator role. After granting the necessary permissions, changing the 'Domain Restricted Sharing' organization policy rule to "Allow all" resolved the above error.
1.Grant the "Organization Policy Administrator" role to the account in "IAM".
1
2.Change the 'Domain Restricted Sharing' in "Organization Policy".
2
3

You need to check that the value for the allowed domains for the organization policy match the domain that you are trying to add (in your case, system.gserviceaccount.com).
It seems that the org policy does not has that value.
